# Is the $L_1$ Minimizer can be calculated per component?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization

Let $\mathcal{X} = \left\{ \mathbf{x}_{i} \right\}_{i=1}^N$ be a set of vectors where $\mathbf{x}_{i} \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$.

I know that the minimizer of $\arg \min_{\mathbb{y}} \sum_{i = 1}^{N} \left\| \mathbf{y} - \mathbf{x}_{i} \right\|_2^2$ is the mean of the set.
I also can calculate it per component, so I can calculate $d$ times the mean of $N$ scalars.

I know the minimizer of $\arg \min_{\mathbb{y}} \sum_{i = 1}^{N} \left\| \mathbf{y} - \mathbf{x}_{i} \right\|_1$ is the median.

Can I calculate it in the same way? By calculating $d$ medians of $N$ scalars (Components of each vector)?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually decompose the problem by coordinate:

$$
\|y - x_i\|_1 = \sum_{j = 1}^d |y_j - (x_i)_j| \implies
\sum_{i} \|y - x_i\|_1 =
\sum_{i, j} |y_j - (x_i)_j| =
\sum_{j = 1}^d \left(
\sum_{i = 1}^n |y_j - (x_i)_j|
\right)
$$

Therefore, you have

$$
\mathrm{min}_{y} \sum_{i = 1}^n \|y - x_i\|_1 =
\left( \mathrm{min}_{y_1} \sum_{i = 1}^n |y_1 - (x_i)_1| \right) + \dots +
\left(
\mathrm{min}_{y_d} \sum_{i = 1}^n |y_d - (x_i)_d|
\right).
$$

Each of the one-dimensional problems is solved by the median across the corresponding coordinate.

Comment: So why L1 minimizers don't use this?

Comment: What do you mean by L1 minimizers?